# Regex for valid phone numbers

Tags: regex

I'am having some issues creating a regex to validate phone numbers.
The validations that i need is the following:

has either 3 digits or between 7 and 12 digits (inclusive)
 - can have the optional '+' character in the beginning (before any digit)
 - can start with '00', in which case it shouldn't start with the '+' sign
 - if it starts with '00', these two digits don't count to the maximum number of digits
 - cannot have any letters
 - cannot have any symbol aside from the beginning '+' sign
 - cannot have any whitespace between the '+' sign and the first digit but can have any amount of whitespace in all other places

What I have is the following -> `^[+]{0,1}[-\s/0-9]*$`

Comment: Use `^(?:00|\+)[0-9\s\/-]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
^(\+|00)?(\d\s*){7,12}$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `(\+|00)?` optional + or 00
- `(\d\s*){7,12}` a digit followed by zero or more spaces, 7 to 12 times
- `$` end of string

Comment: It works. Thanks for the solution and explantion :)

Comment: I did some tests and it does't work was it should. The number is only valid if it has either a + or 00 at the begining of the number. This regex does not prevent that.

Comment: @BrunoRamos As you said "+" was optional, I thought "00" (being a replacement for "+") was also optional. Just remove the "?" in the second part. "?" means "optional", works just like {0,1}